# Why @state var in SwiftUI doesn't changing my view?

Tags: swift, swiftui, state

I can't understand why on button tap doesn't appearing additional view

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var isGlassesMenuShow = false
@State public var bgColor = Color.gray

var body: some View {
    HStack{
  
        VStack{
           
            SceneView(scene: getSirenHead(), options: [.autoenablesDefaultLighting,.allowsCameraControl]).frame(width:UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 50, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height-100)
            GlassView(isOn: $isGlassesMenuShow)
        }
            Button("", action: {
               
                self.isGlassesMenuShow = true
                
            })}
```

And this is view class

```
struct GlassView: View {
@Binding var isOn: Bool

var body: some View {
if isOn{
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack{
    ZStack{
    Button("", action: {
        
    }).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.white)
                Image("glass")
                    .resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 50)}
    ZStack{
    Button("", action: {
        
    }).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.white)
                Image("glass2")
                    .resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 50)}
    }}
}
else{
    EmptyView()
}
```

}
}

the desired view simply does not appear when the button is pressed, but when you manually in the code set true it appears

Comment: What are you pressing? The label for the first button is empty. You have nothing to click on.

Comment: there is a label, I just removed the unnecessary from the code

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it does work, when you press the button "click me", GlassView appears.
Here is my test code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isGlassesMenuShow = false
    @State public var bgColor = Color.gray
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            VStack{
                Text("testing testing")
                GlassView(isOn: $isGlassesMenuShow)
            }
            Button("click me", action: { // <--- press this button and GlassView appears
                self.isGlassesMenuShow = true
            })}
    }
}

struct GlassView: View {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        if isOn{
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack{
                    ZStack{
                        Button("button1", action: {
                            
                        }).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.white)
                        Image(systemName: "globe").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 50)}
                    ZStack{
                        Button("button2", action: {
                            
                        }).frame(width: 100, height: 100).background(Color.white)
                        Image(systemName: "info").resizable().frame(width: 100, height: 50)}
                }}
        }
        else{
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my test code does not work for someone? Let me know what it is that does not work.

Comment: Your code is working, but I can't understand why for my view it isn't working, because the is the same....

Comment: I did it! Button didn't work, because there was no label